# How to inspect/modify Windows Firewall rules while the Windows Firewall/ICS service is stopped and disabled?

Tags: windows, firewall

I'm trying to fix up my friend's remote Windows Server 2003 R2 machine.

I have Remote Desktop access at the moment. However, I notice that Windows Firewall/Internet Connection Sharing service of the remote machine is disabled, which seems to be a bad idea. If I enable and start the service now, I may lose my Remote Desktop access in case the exception rule for Remode Desktop has not been defined in Windows Firewall.

So I need a way to inspect and modify exception rules even as the Windows Firewall/ICS service is stopped and disabled.

Does anybody know how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `netsh` utility.

For example, I used this batch file to allow incoming connections on a specific port:

```
netsh routing ip nat add portmapping name="Internet" proto=TCP publicip=0.0.0.0 publicport=%1 privateip=127.0.0.1 privateport=%1
```

Note that the above command adds an Inbound Filter rule, which is not the same as Windows Firewall rules. It's an additional mechanism (part of Routing and Remote Access) to filter packets at a lower level.